# Can you increase the distance walked on a running machine?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can you clock off some distance using a running machine? Or do you have to be outside.

Comment: It is based on GPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have GPS movement - a running machine won't work. Technically you don't *have* to even be outside, but you'll obviously get much better GPS reception outside.

I often leave my app open and get small amounts of 'walking' from the GPS re-fixing its position. It's not a lot, but it helps get a bit closer to the eggs hatching.

In addition, remember there is a speed limit - so driving, taking the train etc. is only going to count when moving real slow.

Answer (score 1):

Your movement is tracked through a mixture of your phone's GPS and Pedometer. So running on a treadmill is not going to work.

Comment: There's definitely no pedometer element to it. It's just based on distance traveled below a certain speed. I've gotten small amounts in the car from spots of slowing down to a stop, and some others have gotten small amounts of distance simply from GPS drift.